# Characterizing covariance of sensor with many pairs of measurements

Tags: covariance

I am trying to characterize the covariance of a spectrograph's response (a spectrograph measures the intensity of light at many wavelengths, and wavelengths correspond to pixels on a CCD detector). I have many science measurements (spectra) taken with this instrument, from which I am able to isolate pairs (and occasionally triplets) of observations that correspond to the same object and should represent different realizations of the same signal. Each spectrum also has an inverse-variance spectrum of the same length. I have around 2000 such pairs and triplets, and each spectrum has 4000 or so pixels.

If all the observations were of the same source, then finding the covariance would be simple, even given occasional bad data. But, such measurements are not available. I have two ideas:

1. Is there a way to use the pairs/triplets to construct many estimates of the covariance, and then combine all 2000 into a better estimate?
2. Alternately, could I take the difference between pairs and use the harmonic sum of the inverse-variances to find the inverse-variance for the difference, and then just use those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with...

Let's say you have observation $i$ of object $a$ is denoted $S^a_i$. The difference between two such observations is $D^a_{i,~j}$ for $i \ne j$. A given object $a$ with $N$ total observations will have $N \choose 2$ unique combinations, the set

$$U^a = \left( \array{D^a_{0,~1} \\ ... \\ D^a_{N,~N-1}} \right)$$

After accumulating such sets for all $M$ objects, you get

$$U^* = \left( \array{U^{a_1} \\ ... \\ U^{a_M}} \right)$$

Each $D^a_{i,~j}$ also has an inverse-variance (weight) that's constructed from quadrature-addition of the individual constituent observations' inverse-variance:

$$W^a = \left( \array{\frac{1}{1 / w^a_0 + 1 / w^a_1} \\ ... \\ \frac{1}{1 / w^a_N + 1 / w^a_{N-1}}} \right)$$

$W^*$ is constructed in the same way as $U^*$.

Finally, you assume that individual differences $D^a_{i,~j}$ should center around zero, so you use a simplified form of the [general covariance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Calculating_the_sample_covariance), after incorporating weights...

$$K = \frac{(W^* ~ U^*)^T \cdot (W^* ~ U^*)}{W^{*^T} \cdot W^* - 1}$$

where element-wise multiplication is denoted by the two tensors offset by a space, standard, "matrix-multiplication" a dot ( $\cdot$ ), and element-wise division fraction notation.